# To use custom post types, or not to use

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I have in the past few years done more and more development in Wordpress and would like to get some feedback about custom post types/taxonomies.

What are the pros/cons of using custom post types, rather than creating your own database tables and your own admin pages? I have myself always used posts/taxonomies, but found myself restricted by the pre-defined relationships between each. I also noticed some modules do use them, some don't.

What would you guys suggest, and if both could apply, what's the logic behind it?

Comment: This is an open ended question, and open ended questions tend to result in opinion and not in definitive answers. Pro for one person is a con for another depending on personal preference about software organization, maintenance, aesthetics or whatever.. Please try to edit your question and give a concrete scenario to refer to.

Comment: …by "custom posts" I suppose you are referring to custom post types "CPT"?

Comment: This is just way too broad with too many variables. Exact usage depends on the project at hand

Comment: What restrictions have you found? I think in almost everything is already done for you: CRUD and REST APIs, user access control, object cache ready, extensible by third party developers .... One of the things I like more of WordPress, and one of the main reasons I think it has that great market share, is the high level of abstraction on the concept of content and content clasification. So, what kind of restrictions have you have that make you to think about building all of that from scratch? I think that is the real question.

Comment: The question is MEANT to be broad. I am not trying to fix a particular issue, I am trying to understand a logic. And yes I am trying to avoid getting people's preferences, I am just trying to figure out what the best method is, and why. In ANY scenario. Meaning, why would you pick one over the other, in what case.

Comment: With all due respect, I think you don't understand my question. The question is specific to the correct and logic use of custom posts, and is broad as it's not specific to one issue. Do you really need to face a specific issue to start wondering if your method of coding is the right one?!

Comment: People that want to read pointless long drivels should post question on quora ;)

Comment: I think this question can be interesting and very constructive, it can fall in "Some subjective questions allowed" part of the site's rules. But to be constructive you would need to describe what kind of restrictions you have found and made you to think that WordPress standard content management is not enough or what aspects it lacks.

Comment: I am very surprised people don't try to see further than a FAQ. Try to understand the depth of the question. I have years of experience in development, and were genuinely expecting some very constructive answers about this topic.

Comment: @Fran, "correct" is when it works to the spec and do not take more then the allocated time and budget. This is a practical software development site  and not a religion or academia, there are many ways to reach the same result, which is "better" depends mainly on your specific setting.

Comment: @Fran the problem with your question is that, without knowing the restrictions you have found, nobody can tell you what is best apart of "I prefer to always use WordPress content management system" or "I prefer to use my own tables". That is why I asked you about specifics restrictions you have found. If you don't describe them, your question has not much sense in the context of this site. I hope you understand it and don't get angry with anyone.

Comment: What I read is "I don't want to bother explaining any use case". Is that really the community spirit?

Comment: @cybmeta Thanks for understanding my question. I explicitly didn't give any example just so I could avoid the answer being focused on one particular issue.

Comment: *All:* Please stop the comment explosion, _now_. There's [chat] for that. @Fran Please see the [help] to read why open ended and opinionated questions are a problem. If you would like to change that, please post on [meta]. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of thumb in wordpress development is that you should stick with the highest level API you can use. From software development perspective it helps you get a better documentation for your code and reduce the maintenance cost due to the backward compatibility policy.

As CPTs have wrapper APIs in core and costume tables do not, it is easy to see that by default you should prefer CPT, and there should be very very very strong reason to use additional tables.

The only somewhat plausible reason to use additional table is if you need to be able to drop it, or you need a different index structure. Even then not sure if you will gain any actual performance benefit over doing it with less optimized queries.

[joking] If you don't have 20k reputation on this site, additional tables are just not for you [/joking]

Comment: @cybmeta, tnx, yes that was part of why I wrote it, to end that discussion :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will accept it because you are the only one who really bothered to.